# How to change the expected type?

Tags: python

Good morning everyone. I'm working on this inventory project. I keep getting type error:
"super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type"

I'm trying to connect the __str__method from the InventoryItem to the __str__method from the Book class.

Book class:

```
from inventory_item import InventoryItem


class Book(InventoryItem):
    def __init__(self, name: str, count: int, unit_cost: float, hardback: bool):
        super().__init__(name, count, unit_cost)
        self.hardback = hardback

    def get_item_input(self):
        super().get_item_input()

        get_hardback = str(input("Is this a hardback book (y/n)? "))

        if get_hardback == "y" or get_hardback == "Y":
            self.hardback = True
            return str(self.hardback)
        else:
            self.hardback = False
            return str(self.hardback)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + " Hardback: " + self.hardback


#I was testing to see if it works, before using it in other modules
get_book = Book("", 0, 0.00, True)
new_obj2 = Book.get_item_input(get_book)

#ERROR happens here:
new_obj3 = Book.__str__(new_obj2) 
print(new_obj)
```

The output of Book Class:

```
Enter the item name: m
Enter the item count: 12
Enter the unit cost: 12
Is this a hardback book (y/n)? y

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/book.py", line 33, in <module>
    new_obj3 = Book.__str__(new_obj2)
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/book.py", line 28, in __str__
    return super().__str__() + " Hardback: " + self.hardback
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

That's what get_item_input looks like from the InventoryItem class:

```
    def get_item_input(self):
        # Get item name
        while True:
            name1 = input('Enter the item name: ')
            if ',' in name1:
                print('Item names cannot contain commas.')
            else:
                self.name = name1
                break
        # Get item count
        while True:
            try:
                count1 = int(input('Enter the item count: '))
                if count1 < 0:
                    print('Item count must be 0 or greater.')
                else:
                    self.count = count1
                    break
            except:
                print('Item count must be an integer.')
        # Get unit cost
        while True:
            try:
                unit_cost1 = float(input('Enter the unit cost: '))
                if unit_cost1 < 0:
                    print('Unit cost must be 0 or greater.')
                else:
                    self.unit_cost = unit_cost1
                    break
            except:
                print('Unit cost must be an integer.')

        return InventoryItem(name1, count1, unit_cost1)

    def get_retail_value(self):
        retail_value = self.unit_cost * self.count
        return retail_value

    def __str__(self):
        retail_value = self.get_retail_value()
        pass_it = "Name: " + self.name + \
                  " Count: " + str(self.count) + " Cost: " + str(self.unit_cost) + " Retail value: " + str(retail_value)
        return pass_it
```

I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What's `InventoryItem`?

Comment: use `super().__init__(name, count, unit_cost)`

Comment: @chepner that's the main class I imported

Comment: `Book.__str__(new_obj2)` fails because `new_obj2` is not a `Book`; it's a string, because that's what your `get_item_input` method returns.

Comment: @kaya3 that makes sense, I figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of kaya3 from comments, I figured it out. I wasn't returning Book at all.
Here is the working code:

```
class Book(InventoryItem):
    def __init__(self, name: str, count: int, unit_cost: float, hardback: bool):
        super().__init__(name, count, unit_cost)
        self.hardback = hardback

    def get_item_input(self):
        super().get_item_input()

        get_hardback = str(input("Is this a hardback book (y/n)? "))

        if get_hardback == "y" or get_hardback == "Y":
            self.hardback = True
#THIS IS WHAT I ADDED NEW:
            return Book(self.name, self.count, self.unit_cost, self.hardback)
        else:
            self.hardback = False
#THIS IS WHAT I ADDED NEW:
            return Book(self.name, self.count, self.unit_cost, self.hardback)

    def __str__(self):
        #pass_it = self.get_item_input()
        return super().__str__() + " Hardback: " + str(self.hardback)


new_obj2 = Book("", 0, 0.00, True)
new_obj3 = Book.get_item_input(new_obj2)
get_book = Book.__str__(new_obj2)
print(new_obj3)
```